# Using Max Database Size option in ADO causes the Open command to throw

Tags: c++, sql-server-ce, ado

I have a SQLCompact database that I'm trying to access using `ADO` and `C++`. However due to the size of the database (300MB, over the default 256MB limit), I have to specify the `Max Database Size` in the connection string. However doing so causes the `.Open(...)` function to throw.

The code I'm using:

```
HRESULT hr = conn.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection), NULL);
conn->Open(L"Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=test.sdf;Max Database Size=512", L"", L"",adConnectUnspecified);
```

The error:

> HR: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED
>
> Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."
>
> Message: "IDispatch error #3105"

Note:

I've tried using the same code, with a smaller database and removing `Max Database Size` from the connection string and it works as expected. Adding the `Max Database Size` again causes the problem to reappear, therefore my assumption that it's the one causing the error.

Any thoughts? How can I work with databases over the `Provider` default size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use:

```
Provider= Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=test.sdf;ssce:Max Database Size=512
```

(same applies to password and other SQL Compact specific keywords)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it as soon as I have a chance (side note: your SQLCompact blog posts and tools are amazing, thank you =) )